# How to check if two numbers have the same value and store them in an Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a code that search my API and brings a lot of stuff. I already picked up the data that I want (consumption and date) I picked up this using map and turned into an object.

```
            const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
            await api.get('measures/user/' + user).then(res => {
                setMeasures(res.data.measure)
            });
            const mapStuff = measures.map((data) => {
                let month = parseInt(data.creationDate.slice(3, 5));
                let consumption = parseFloat(data.WaterConsumption);
                return{
                    month: month,
                    consumption
                }
            });
```

This brings me a array of Objects:
`[{consumption: 30, month: 10}, {consumption: 40, month: 11}, {consumption: 35, month: 10}]`
What I want to do is, create a new object checking if the months are equal, if they are equal I want to sum the consumption (basically a reduce) like this: `[{consumption: 65, month: 10}, {consumption: 40, month: 11}]`. But I can't figure out how to do this. I started a forEach, but I don't know what can I use to compare?.

```
            mapStuff.forEach(myObject => {
                if (myObject.month === myObject.month) {
                    
                }
            });
```

Does Anyone have a clue on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to maintain a map of `month` to `consumption` totals whiel you loop through the data, and then at the end convert that map into an array of the object you want. Here's an example:

```
const totals = new Map();
for (const data of measures) {
    const month = parseInt(data.creationDate.slice(3, 5));
    const consumption = parseFloat(data.WaterConsumption);
    totals.set(month, (totals.get(month) ?? 0) + consumption);
}
const mapStuff = [...totals.entries()].map(([month, consumption]) => ({month, consumption}));
```

Live Example:

```js
const measures = [
    {
        creationDate: "xx/10/yyyy", 
        WaterConsumption: "30",
    },
    {
        creationDate: "xx/11/yyyy",
        WaterConsumption: "40",
    },
    {
        creationDate: "xx/10/yyyy",
        WaterConsumption: "35",
    },
];

const totals = new Map();
for (const data of measures) {
    const month = parseInt(data.creationDate.slice(3, 5));
    const consumption = parseFloat(data.WaterConsumption);
    totals.set(month, (totals.get(month) ?? 0) + consumption);
}
const mapStuff = [...totals.entries()].map(([month, consumption]) => ({month, consumption}));

console.log(mapStuff);
```

---

Side note: In your original code, you have:

```
const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
await api.get('measures/user/' + user).then(res => {
    setMeasures(res.data.measure)                // <===================
});
const mapStuff = measures.map((data) => {        // <===================
// ...
```

Note that `measures` in the `map` call will not be the value you just set via `setMeasures` above. State updates are asynchronous. If you want to build `mapStuff` when `measures` changes, either do that above when setting measures or do it in a `useEffect` callback depending on `measures`.

Also note that mixing `await` with explicit promise handling methods like `.then` and `.catch` is not best practice. Just use `await`. For instance re the above:

```
const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
const res = await api.get('measures/user/' + user);
setMeasures(res.data.measure);
```

*(That just addresses the `await` aspect.)*